# How to find and fix the origin of invalid Unicode character generated by LyX?

Tags: errors, lyx, pdf, unicode

I am getting these errors when either directly generating a pdf in LyX or running `pdflatex` on the generated .tex.

```tex
Overfull \hbox (36.72682pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2163--2166
 [][] 
[49]
Underfull \vbox (badness 3815) has occurred while \output is active [50 <./obr/
Businger_phim.png (PNG copy)> <./obr/Businger_phih.png (PNG copy)>] [51 <./obr/
Arya11.5.png>]

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ŀ (U+0140)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.2288 \chapter
               {Konvektivní mezní vrstva}
? [52 <./obr/Garrat3.5.png (PNG copy)>]

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ŀ (U+0140)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.2288 \chapter
               {Konvektivní mezní vrstva}
? 
[53 <./obr/HoltslagNieuwstadt1986fig2.png (PNG copy)>]

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ŀ (U+0140)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.2288 \chapter
               {Konvektivní mezní vrstva}
? 
[54 <./obr/HoltslagNieuwstadt1986fig1.png (PNG copy)>]
Kapitola 11
```

The file uses the UTF-8 encoding and is written in Czech and uses

```tex
\documentclass[oneside,czech]{amsbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[unicode=true]
 {hyperref}
```

As I am aware, the character ŀ does not appear anywhere in the .tex file. I also tried Okteta to search for 0x140 or for 0xC5 0x80 but the search shows nothing. How can I find the origin for this?

The generated pdf looks reasonable, but the table of content for pdf navigation ends before the chapter that is mentioned in the error message (Konvektivní mezní vrstva). I tried changing the name but it does not change anything.

---

With `\errorcontextlines=1000`, as suggested by David Carlisle, the error looks like this

```tex
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ŀ (U+0140)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                  \endgroup 
\UTFviii@defined ...ax \UTFviii@undefined@err {#1}
                                                  \else \PackageError {input...

\@tempa ->{\protect \@upprep ŀ
                               KÁLOVÁNÍ MIMO PřÍZEMNÍ VRSTVU}
\sectionrunhead ...percasenonmath \@tempa \@tempa 
                                                  \endgroup \fi 
\rightmark ->\expandafter \@secondoftwo \botmark 
                                                 {}{}
\@oddhead ...\protect \thanks@warning }\rightmark 
                                                  {}{}\hfil \llap {\thepage }
\@outputpage ...lor \hb@xt@ \textwidth {\@thehead 
                                                  }\color@endbox }\dp \@temp...

\@opcol ...lumn \@outputdblcol \else \@outputpage 
                                                  \fi \global \@mparbottom \...
<output> ...specialoutput \else \@makecol \@opcol 
                                                  \@startcolumn \@whilesw \i...

\newpage ...prevdepth \fi \fi \vfil \penalty -\@M 
                                                  
\clearpage ...opskip \hbox {}\fi \fi \fi \newpage 
                                                  \write \m@ne {}\vbox {}\pe...

\cleardoublepage ->\clearpage 
                              {\pagestyle {empty}\cleardouble@page }
\chapter ->\if@openright \cleardoublepage 
                                          \else \clearpage \fi \thispagestyl...
l.2290 \chapter
               {Konvektivní mezní vrstva}
?
```

this appears to be in the name of a section that is displayed on the top of the page and that contains a capital letter Š (U+0160).

```tex
Podobně v modelech můžeme určit toky u zemského povrchu z hodnot teploty
a rychlosti v nejnižší modelové hladině.

\section{Škálování mimo přízemní vrstvu}

Moninova-Obuchovova teorie podobnosti platí v přízemní vrstvě a jen
v určitém rozmezí stability mimo extrémy jak ve stabilním, tak v instabilním
```

The letter Š is missing in the resulting pdf and `FIX-ME` was there instead when I redefined the U+0140 character.

[image]

Please also note the small ř instead of the capital Ř.

I now noticed, that another letter gets corrupted in a similar location:

[image]

from

```tex
\section{Empirické podobnostní funkce a jejich důsledky}
```

That means that Ů/ů U+016E/F was changed into ŏ U+014F.

The texts in the titles within the text itself are correct.

[image]

Please also note that when opening the .tex file with UTF-8 encoding, kwrite complains that it contains illegal character and cannot be saved. However, the suspicious section titles appear to be OK.

---

I now believe that the problem with the pdf navigation is a separate one and I will perhaps ask a separate question.

Comment: in your preamble add `\errorcontextlines=1000` then show the full error message from `!` to `?` in a code block so lines are preserved

Comment: Then add `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0140}{FIX-ME!!!}` and  show the resulting output

Comment: The error is *before* `\chapter`. What do you have there? Something that produces a few images with a loop, I believe. TeX shows where it's at and that error message means that `\chapter` hasn't yet been processed.

Comment: bingo: `percasenonmath ` the class is applying primitive `\uppercase`  breaking the utf-8 encoding.  The details of how to fix depend on your latex version as `\MakeUppercase` was reimplemented recently to better work wth Unicode. Do you have `LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have "LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>"

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава oh a bit old but I think my answer will still apply

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I'm glad the answer works for you! Can you please send a .lyx file that produces the error to me? My email address is: skostysh@lyx.org. I cannot reproduce the error in LyX. I want to see your file so I can see if LyX can automatically add the correct code so that you don't manually have to add the package to the preamble. Thanks!

Comment: @scottkosty you should get the error if you have amsbook, and a section with three pages

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can reproduce, thanks! Is this a bug somewhere? In theory, what should LyX condition on when deciding whether to load the `textcase` package?

Comment: @scottkosty amsbook was never updated to cope with utf-8, but it does check for `textcase` and use that instead of its own code if loaded. Since last year `textcase` does nothing really as the format `\MakeUppercase` has a better version, so it just uses that. But loading the package makes amsbook avoid its version so does the right thing in old  and new formats. Ideally it would not be needed, and the AMS will update amsbook, but I would not hold my breath waiting for that...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That is very helpful. Since `textcase` is so lightweight, would it be reasonable for LyX to just always load `textcase` whenever `amsbook` is used?

Comment: @scottkosty yes until amsbook gets an update, but it shouldn't do any harm even if amsbook gets fixed so it isn't needed

Comment: @DavidCarlisle perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

%\usepackage{textcase}
\begin{document}

\section{Škálování mimo přízemní vrstvu}
xxx\newpage
xxx\newpage
xxx

\end{document}
```

Produces

```
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ŀ (U+0140)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.11 \end{document}
                   
?
```

If you uncomment `textcase` you get

[image]

Comment: Great! I added the package into the LyX preamble and the error is fixed.